# Navegar entre activitys

Tags: android, kotlin

Tengo 4 activitys(a,b,c,d) quiero que el usuario al presionar el botón de atrás regrese siempre a la actividad a pero si esta en la actividad c regrese a la b.

En la actividad a solo hay un botón para avanzar a la actividad b,
en la b hay dos botones uno para avanzar a la actividad c y otro para regresar a la actividad a,
en la c hay dos botones uno para avanzar a la actividad d y otro para regresar a la actividad b y
en la d solo hay un botón para regresar a la actividad a.

lo que hice fue usar intent para crear la actividad y destruir en la que estaba

```
   val btnNext= Intent(this, ActivityC::class.java)
   startActivity(btnNext)
   this.finish()
```

pero en la actividad b no la puedo destruir para que regrese de la c

```
   val btnNext= Intent(this, ActivityC::class.java)
   startActivity(btnNext)
```

y al avanzar a la d y regresar me regresa a la b no a la a, la forma en que lo hice fue por medio de intent.putExtra mandar datos a la actividad b y mediante un if saber si vengo de la actividad d o c y regresar a la "actividad a" o "actividad b".

¿Hay alguna otra manera de hacerlo?

Aún no entiendo bien como usar las FLAGS en el intent y el launchMode dentro del manifiest

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Seria ideal utilizaras fragments y utilizaras el componente nuevo de navegación

Para incluir compatibilidad con Navigation en tu proyecto, agrega las siguientes dependencias al archivo build.gradle de tu app:

```
    dependencies {
  val nav_version = "2.3.5"

  // Java language implementation
  implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:$nav_version")
  implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:$nav_version")

  // Kotlin
  implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:$nav_version")
  implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:$nav_version")

  // Feature module Support
  implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-dynamic-features-fragment:$nav_version")

  // Testing Navigation
  androidTestImplementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-testing:$nav_version")

  // Jetpack Compose Integration
  implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:2.4.0-alpha06")
}
```

Cómo crear un gráfico de navegación

La navegación ocurre entre los destinos de tu app, es decir, en cualquier lugar de tu app en el que los usuarios puedan navegar. Estos destinos están conectados a través de acciones.

Un gráfico de navegación es un archivo de recursos que contiene todos tus destinos y acciones. El gráfico representa todas las rutas de navegación de tu app.

En la figura 1, se muestra una representación visual de un gráfico de navegación para una app de muestra, que contiene seis destinos conectados por cinco acciones. Cada destino se representa con una miniatura de vista previa, mientras que las acciones de conexión se representan a través de flechas que muestran cómo los usuarios pueden navegar de un destino al otro.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Info oficial https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-getting-started

Comment: Es interesante lo relacionado a Navigation , pero como se realizaría lo que quiere en la pregunta

Comment: Esto es un copypaste de la documentación y es más una orientación que una respuesta. Deberías colocarlo como comentario.

Comment: al final agregue android:launchMode="singleTask" en el manifiest en la MainActivity.
cree un método publico en la actividad B 
public fun Close(){
        this.finish()
    } 
En la actividad D cree otro método que llamo en el botón de regresar y en la función onBackPressed()
fun Home(){
        val actB = ActivityB();
        actB.Close()
        val start = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(start)
        this.finish()
    }